# Qdrant payload index without filter

Tags: payload, qdrant

I am currently using Qdrant version 1.7.3. I am looking for a way to fetch payloads without using a filter. Specifically, I need to retrieve payloads by providing an ID or fetching the first 'n' results without having to use a filter.

My question is whether I need to define a payload index if I do not have a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. If you're not using any filters, you're better off without a payload index.